# Is there any benefits on using no spaces and short table aliases in queries?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Do queries with no excessive spaces and small table aliases stress the MySQL server less or is  the difference negligible?

```
SELECT my_table.a, my_table.b, my_table.c, my_table.d
FROM table_containing_data as my_table
WHERE my_table.a = 1 AND my_table.b = 1 AND my_table.c = 1 AND my_table.d = 1
```

vs.

```
SELECT t.a,t.b,t.c,t.d
FROM table_containing_data t
WHERE t.a=1 AND t.b=1 AND t.c=1 AND t.d=1
```

I am fully aware of the readability of each of them. This question is purely hypothetical. If the difference (when running queries like these hundreds of thousands of times a day) is significant, I might change how my query engine works.

Comment: Even after when the amount of these queries rise up to millions?

Comment: that won't make much difference since the result to be fetched is same.

Comment: If you do hundreds of thousands of queries during the course of the day, it might add a few seconds to the whole thing. Does it really matter whether 12 hours of work actually takes 12 hours + 10 seconds?

Comment: No I don't think it matters. I'm curious if there's such servers where you are required to skip all whitespaces etc. to minimize stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for billions of queries, whitespace in your queries is not going to make the difference.

Databases cache queries and execution plans anyway, so if you end up sending the same query over and over again (why aren't you using prepared statements?) any decent database will not have to parse the whole thing again. Of course that only applies if you don't mix SQL and data in the same string.. which is usually done with MySQL. So here's another reason to use prepared statements!

Also, compared to actually retrieving data from the disk (which, by the way, should happen rarely if your database is not huge - you want LOTS of RAM in your database machines to have as much as possible in memory) any parsing etc. is negligible.

Comment: What if the query keeps changing so it cannot be cached? Will whitespaces etc. make a difference then?

Comment: Even then.. you probably don't have that many different versions. In any case, the time spend parsing the query is negligible.